# EWS - One or more subscriptions in the request reside on another Client Access server

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-javascript-api

I got this error when I'm using streaming subscription with impersonation.
After the connection opened and receive notification successfully for minutes, it just pops up a bunch of this for almost all subscriptions.

How can I avoid this error?

```
One or more subscriptions in the request reside on another Client Access server. GetStreamingEvents won't proxy in the event of a batch request., The Availability Web Service instance doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform the request
```

I need to keep the connection stable and avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't use affinity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-maintain-affinity-between-group-of-subscriptions-and-mailbox-server

Also if its a multi threaded application ExchangeService isn't thread safe and shouldn't be used across multiple threads.

Comment: I did, but sometimes ews didn't respond  X-BackEndOverrideCookie so I just ignore adding it.